# How can I use PHP or any other server side script to create automatic html tags whenever a new image is added to the server stored image folder

Tags: php, html, perl, python-3.x

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body class="layouts" id="www-cssplay-co-uk">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Demo</h1>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul class="main"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <input checked="checked" id="pic1" name="large" type="radio"> 
        <input id="pic2" name="large" type="radio">
        <input id="pic3" name="large" type="radio">
        <input id="pic4" name="large" type="radio"> 
        <input id="pic5" name="large" type="radio"> 
        <input id="pic6" name="large" type="radio"> 
        <input id="pic7" name="large" type="radio"> 
        <input id="pic8" name="large" type="radio"> 
        <input id="pic9" name="large" type="radio"> 
        <input id="pic10" name="large" type="radio"> 
        <input id="pic11" name="large" type="radio"> 
        <input id="pic12" name="large" type="radio"> 
        <input id="pic13" name="large" type="radio"> 
        <input id="pic14" name="large" type="radio"> 
        <input id="pic15" name="large" type="radio"> 
        <input id="pic16" name="large" type="radio"> 
        <input id="pic17" name="large" type="radio">
        <input id="pic18" name="large" type="radio"> 
        <input id="pic19" name="large" type="radio">
        <input id="pic20" name="large" type="radio">
        <input id="pic21" name="large" type="radio">
        <input id="pic22" name="large" type="radio">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="main-scroll">
                <div class="main-inner"><img alt="" src="images/1.jpg"></div>
                <div class="main-inner"><img alt="" src="images/2.jpg"></div>
                <div class="main-inner"><img alt="" src="images/3.jpg"></div>
                <div class="pad-bottom"></div>
            </div>
        </div><!--
        -->
        <div id="info">
            <div id="info-scroll">
                <div class="pad-top"></div>
                <div class="info-inner">
                    <label for="pic1">
                     <img alt="" src="images/1.jpg"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="info-inner">
                    <label for="pic2"><img alt="" src="images/2.jpg"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="info-inner">
                    <label for="pic3"><img alt="" src="images/3.jpg"></label>
                </div>  
                <div class="pad-bottom"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <ul class="sub"></ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The image folder is hosted on the server side. It currently has 3 images. I want to write a php script that does 2 things when a new image is added to the folder. 1st, it automatically creates a "`<div class="main-inner"><img alt="" src="images/x.jpg"></div>`" tag (where 'x.jpg' would be the new image) in the 'main-inner' div area. 2nd, adds a  `<div class="info-inner"><label for="pic3"><img alt="" src="images/x.jpg"></label></div>`tag in the 'info-inner' div area.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It sounds like you should dynamically generate the divs based on the contents of your images folder when the page loads, not have a separate scripts that modifies the HTML when the image is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the folder contents when the page loads, then generate your code for each file in the folder.

Something like this should get you started:

```
<?php

$folder = 'images';

$images = scandir($folder);
$images = array_diff($images, array('..', '.'));  // remove '..' and '.' from array

foreach ($images as $i => $image) {
    $id = 'pic' . $i;
    $divHTML .= "<div class=\"main-inner\"><img src=\"$folder/$image\"></div>";
    $labelHTML .= "<div class=\"info-inner\"><label for=\"$id\"><img src=\"$folder/$image\"></label></div>";
}
?>
<html>
<?php echo $divHTML ?>
<?php echo $labelHTML ?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a directory in some folder on server
NOTE: you can add many images and this code will show all images that pasted on that folder.

```html
 <?php 
$directory = "C:/wamp/www/Test/images/";
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");
$count = count($images)+1;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body class="layouts" id="www-cssplay-co-uk">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Demo</h1>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul class="main"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
 <?php foreach($images as $key=>$value)
 { 
  $whatIWant = substr($value, strpos($value, "C:/wamp/www/") + 12);   
  $count = $key+1;
  $cnt = '<input id="pic'.$count.'" name="large" type="radio">';
  echo $cnt;
  ?>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="main-scroll">
<?php 
echo "<div class='main-inner'><img src='http://localhost/".$whatIWant."' alt='' heught=50px width=50px></div>";
} ?>

    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <ul class="sub"></ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```